# Forcing Bower to Install Specific Leaflet Dependency - Resolution Not Working

Tags: leaflet, bower

I am attempting to bower install a variety of leaflet packages. Recently, leaflet upgraded to version 1.1.0 from 1.0.3 which broke several supported libraries. Until the community can fix the issues, I need to have leaflet 1.0.3 installed. Below is part of my bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
     "angular": "~1.5.0",
     "angular-cookies": "~1.5.0",
     "angular-bootstrap": "~2.4.0",
     "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.2",
     "angular-animate": "~1.5.8",
     "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
     "normalize-css": "~3.0.3",
     "modernizr": "~3.2.0",
     "angular-smart-table": "^2.1.8",
     "angular-websocket": "^2.0.0",
     "angular-pageslide-directive": "^2.1.4",
     "ng-scrollbars": "^0.0.11",
     "angular-bootstrap-lightbox": "^0.12.0",
     "angular-leaflet-directive": "leaflet-directive#^0.10.0",
     "Leaflet.extra-markers": "^1.0.6",
     "esri-leaflet": "2.0.7",
     "angular-bootstrap-toggle": "^0.1.2",
     "leaflet-search": "2.7.0",
     "leaflet-draw": "0.4.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     "angular-mocks": "~1.4.7"
  },
  "resolutions": {
     "angular": "^1.4.10",
     "angular-bootstrap": "~2.4.0",
     "leaflet": "1.0.3"
  }
```

However, when I try to force the bower installation using the resolutions, I end up with the following:

[image]

I have another instance of this application running, and it still has 1.0.3 from a prior build. It is also using leaflet-draw 0.4.9, leaflet-search 2.7.0, etc... so I know that the 1.0.3 version is compatible.

Looking at each individual package, each bower.json only requires that leaflet: "^1.0.0".

Why is the bower resolution being ignored and not installing 1.0.3? Why is it not even giving me the option to choose 1.0.3 from the list? I considered downloading a local copy and doing an override, but that is not a preferred solution.